# Is jupyter replicating my data to a cloud server

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

This is a pretty simple question.  I if you download jupyter as a part of Anaconda.  How is your data being secured. When I run jupyter it does go straight to an html page, but that page displays my local folders on the servers I am connected to.

If I make a notebook, will that notebook be stored on a cloud server.  Where does it go, and how can I keep all of my filee ("notebooks) local?

Comment: If you installed manually. Jupyter is actually running a Python Tornado Server locally, and you directly say where your file is stored on your disk. I  don't think it's going to a cloud server.

Comment: For example you ran jupyter notebook --profile=some_profile in folder X, it will show the contents in folder X.

Comment: So if you installed Jupyter on your local machine, then your file should be local.

Answer (score 2):

Jupyter uses no cloud services, and should make no external requests when you are running it locally. The best way to think of a local install of Jupyter notebook is a desktop application that happens to use your web browser for its UI. It talks to the local filesystem, and relays that data to your browser over HTTP on localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No other questions, now I get it